# Duplicate entries in hibernate query result

Tags: java, hibernate

Model O has an element collection of an enum type.

The abbreviated version

```
@Entity
class O {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "o_s", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "o_id") })
    @Column
    private Set<SomeEnum> ss;
}
```

I am querying for all instances of O as follows

```
List<O> ret=session.createCriteria(O.class).list();
```

Now the result list contains duplicate entries.

If, there are 3 values in SS field, then the corresponding entry for O will appear 3 times in the result.

If there are 2 values, then the corresponding entry for O will appear 2 times in the result.

However, the database does not contain duplicate entries.

I have verified this behavior empirically.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's caused by your eagerly loaded collection. You need [to set](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setResultTransformer-org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer-) the [DictinctRootEntityResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.html) to the criteria.

A better alternative, IMO, would be to use HQL:

```
select distinct o from O o
```

Comment: Thanks! Never would have guessed this side effect of Eager loading!